# Gradle : Duplicate classes error using two different libraries but same package name

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, razorpay

So I want to know is there anyway to resolve this issue when you have same classes in local jar file in libs and one imported from gradle via implementation? So what happened is i wanted to use custom-sdk of razorpay for android versions below 21 and standard-sdk for other android versions but both sdks have some common classes and creating below stacktrace

```
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.AdvertisingIdUtil$G__G_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.AdvertisingIdUtil$R$$r_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.AdvertisingIdUtil$d__1_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.AnalyticsConstants found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.AnalyticsEvent found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.AnalyticsProperty found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.AnalyticsUtil found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.B$$W$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.B_$q$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.BaseConstants found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.BaseUtils found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.BaseUtils$2 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.Callback found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.D$_X_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.E$_6$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.E$_j$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.G__G_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.I$_e_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.J$$A_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.J$_0_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.L__R$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.OTP found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.O_$B_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.O__Y_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.PaymentData found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.PaymentResultListener found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.PaymentResultWithDataListener found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.Q$$U_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.Q_$2$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.R$$r_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpAssist found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpAssist$1 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpAssist$2 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpAssist$3 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpAssist$4 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpAssist$5 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpInternalCallback found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpJSONCallback found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpPlugin found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpPluginCompatibilityResponse found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.RzpPluginRegisterCallback found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.Y$_o$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.a_$P$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.b__J_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.d__1_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.g__v_$5 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.l_$w$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.l__d$ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.r$_Y_ found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
  Duplicate class com.razorpay.r$_Y_$5 found in modules jetified-checkout-1.5.16-runtime.jar (com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.16) and jetified-razorpay-android-3.8.10-runtime.jar (razorpay-android-3.8.10.aar)
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude modules like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4') {
        exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
    }
}
```

Or exclude files like this:

```
packagingOptions { exclude 'folder/filename.ext' }
```

You can read more here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html

Comment: were you able to found any solutions here?